# how work around remainder functions?

Tags: algorithm, random, vbscript

I am looking at a formula which is:

> Xn+1 = (a Xn + c)(mod m)
>
> where "n" is number of values which can be from 1 to 1700.   "X" is
>   the number. (n+1 and n are both as sub-scripts)

I am trying to find possible future outcome of a list of pseudo random numbers (each number has a maximum of 6 digits and can have a value from 000001 to 999999).

I know the values of Xn+1 and Xn; for "m" i am using the value "1000000" or "999999", so the result is always 6 digits or less.

I need to find out value of "a".

> **for reference:** Xn=663354 and Xn+1=142516 OR 211941 OR 453794 OR 512535
>   OR 704928 (do not know the order of these numbers but can try them one
>   by one myself, if i just can know how to get a value of "a" in the
>   above equation)

I need to solve this equation or any other if someone can suggest something else.

I am not good at programming; am currently using `MS Excel` to solve this issue.
but can understand a little bit of code in `VB`.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand well you want to determine parameters a and c in your recurrent relation. But you only have one solution of the equation. Your system is underdetermined, you need 3 values Xn+2, Xn+1 and Xn. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system)

If you know c, then this is obvious : You need to solve a linear equation.

Comment: thank you very much dear sir for your response.
following is the algorithm for my solution but i am not able to code it into VB.
    int getRandomNumber() {
    secret = (secret * 663354 + 654321) % 10000001;
    return secret % 100000;
    }

I know the values from X1 to X1700; the basic problem is getting the value of "a", as "c" does not make much difference for my solution.

it will be really helpful for me if you could guide me in this regard.

your advice for solving linear equation is good option; but there too i am stuck due to mod()/remainder function.